# How to estimate errors of experimental values like velocity of a wave which have no theoretical values?

Tags: statistics

I managed to come up that it would be good to use normal distribution and standard deviation acquired from it since there's no value to compare with. But I have no idea how to proceed. Is there any known method which uses normal distribution?

Comment: I think you need to specify your problem a little more carefully. "how to deal with" is not clear without context. Are you trying to estimate the error on your measurement?

Comment: Yes. That's what I wanted to know. I'll take your advice.

Comment: So you basically did an experiment where you got some results, and now you want to know how to calculate the error in them?

Comment: If you search ["error estimation"](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=error+estimation) on this site, you get 71 hits. Many of those contain valuable information that relates to what you are asking about.

Comment: Yes. Especially want a method which uses normal distribution.

Answer (score 0):

The typical situation is:

For "manual" measurements, it's good to suppose a uniform distribution, so

$\sigma = \frac{resolution}{\sqrt{12}}$

If the result is not a direct measurement, but a result of using measurements like the one above into a formula, you have to use error propagation.

However, you must take into account all contributions, like systematic errors, offsets, developers' specifications, and so on.